# Google+ hangout application not getting installed

Tags: 64-bit, plugins, google

The other day I was trying to have a online hangout and logged into Google+ and when I clicked on *start a  hangout*  it prompted me to select if my OS was 32 bit or 64 bit to download a plugin for Ubuntu.

I clicked on 64 bit (I found out that my kernel is 64 bit by using the code `uname -m` in the terminal and the output was `x86_64`).

The download was done and I was redirected to the software center application where I had to install a google-plugin.  When I clicked on it an error pops up saying installation or deletion of software failed.

Do we need to install the plugin also for the hangout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to install [google video chat plugin](http://www.google.com/talk/). Just download it from google website and install it with `sudo dpkg -i PATH/TO/DOWNLOADED_PACKAGE.DEB` from terminal or You can use package like `gdebi` as well. This plugin will install google talk plugin repository and give you upgrades from update manager as well.